# how to execute .py programs without shell?

Tags: python

I have noticed that there are several commercially available programs I have that are partially made in python, but they worked even before I downloaded python. Do they somehow incorporate the interpreter into the executable? How?

Answer (score 0):

Obviously this is platform dependent, but on Windows for example, the [Python on Windows FAQ](http://docs.python.org/2/faq/windows) suggests the following *"See http://www.py2exe.org/ for a distutils extension that allows you to create console and GUI executables from Python code."*

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of packages out there that bundle a py script with its runtime dependancies (ie python & any 3rd party modules)

py2exe
pyinstaller
cx_freeze

py2exe has sort of died a death (I use to use this)
pyinstaller is in active development and has some very nice features BUT does not support py3 at the moment
cx_freeze is equally nice and does support PY3

My preference right now is pyinstaller and is partly why I have held of fully converting a suite of py programs I have to py3